# Buscador Ajax Laravel

Tags: ajax

Tengo una consulta , como podria implementar un metodo ajax para que el buscador traiga la data en el ID que se le dice.(cabe resaltar que el que trae la data y el buscador estan en la misma pagina, la vista que carga todo esto es otra pagina)

```js
$('.data-show-01').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this),
        url = me.attr('href');

    getData(url)
});

function getData(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#loadData').html(response);
        }
    });
};
// con esto traigo la data al carga la pagina html
```

```html
//esta es la pagina que me trae la data

<div class="search">
    <form class="searchForm" action="{{ route( 'tipo',['estado' => Crypt::encrypt($estado_id),'tipo' => Crypt::encrypt($tipo_id)]) }}" method="get">
        <div class="u-relative">
            <input type="text" name='number' class="field__input" placeholder="Buscar por número de expediente">
            <button type='submit' class="searchForm__submit">
                <svg>
                    <use xlink:href="#search"></use>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

//  que llenarse el contenido aqui al momento
// de realizar una busqueda

  <div class="loadData" id="loadData">
                </div>
```

```js
function getData(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#loadData').html(response);
        }
    });
};

$('.data-show-01').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this),
        url = me.attr('href');

    getData(url)
});
```

Comment: Quieres que cuando id me haga un foreach y me muestre todo eso?

Answer (score 0):

agrege este codigo

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $('.searchForm');

    form.bind('submit', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#loadData').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

espero sea de ayuda para los demas

Comment: Marca tu respuesta como aceptada, ayudarás a colaborar con la buena salud del sitio :D

Answer (score 0):

Asi puedes obtener y mostrar lo que quieras buscar

```js
  
  $('.data-show-01').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this),
        url = me.attr('href');

    getData(url)
});

function getData(url) {
   
    $.ajaxSetup({

        headers: {

            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

        }

    }); 
    var search=url;
    
        $.ajax({

           type:'get',
           url:'ruta',
          dataType:'json',
           data:{search:search},
           success:function(data){
           $('#loadData').html(data);

           },
           error:function(data){

           console.log("no funciona");

           }


        });
};
```